# Hibernate NullPointer on INSERTED id when persisting three levels using @Embeddable and cascade

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade, embeddable

I cannot cascade merge with persist three levels of entities using `@EmbeddedId`in the last entity. I have three following entities:
1. Voucher
2. Rate
3. RatePerChannelOverwrite

The `Voucher` is fetched by a service. Then I want to add new `Rate` to the voucher. Then I want to add new `RatePerChannelOverwrite` to the `Rate`. So both `Rate` and `RatePerChannelOverwrite` will have their `@Id` as NULL. This is working.

However later I tried to split `RatePerChannelOverwrite` into two classes and have: `@Embeddable RatePerChannelOverwriteId`. And this setup is failing. The `Rate` referened by `RatePerChannelOverwriteId` never gets its new ID populated.

```
@Entity
public class Voucher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "voucher", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Rate> rates = new HashSet<Rate>();
}

@Entity
public class Rate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "voucher_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Voucher voucher;

    @Column(name = "rate", precision = 2, scale = 9, columnDefinition = "decimal")
    @NumberFormat(pattern = "#0.00")
    private double rate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rate", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RatePerChannelOverwrite> ratePerChannelOverwrites;
}

@Entity
public class RatePerChannelOverwrite {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rate_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Rate rate;

    @Column(name = "channel_id")
    private Integer channelId;

    @Column(name = "rate", precision = 2, scale = 9, columnDefinition = "decimal")
    @NumberFormat(pattern = "#0.00")
    private double rate;
}
```

And this works fine when I do something like that:

```
Voucher voucher = service.getVoucher(123456); 
Rate rate = new Rate(); //NOTE ID IS NULL HERE
rate.setVoucher(voucher);
voucher.getRates().add(rate);

RatePerChannelOverwrite channelRate = new RatePerChannelOverwrite();
channelRate.setRate(rate);
rate.getRatePerChannelOverwrites.add(channelRate);   

voucher = voucher.merge();
```

However when I separate last entity into 2 separate classes, then the `id` of `rate` in `RatePerChannelOverwriteId` is ALWAYS NULL. Somehow cascading here fails.

**NOTE: Third entity has composite key as `@EmbeddedId` with `@ManyToOne`, and this is where the problem shows up.**

```
@Embeddable
public class RatePerChannelOverwriteId {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rate_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Rate rate;

    @Column(name = "channel_id")
    private Integer channelId;
}

@Entity
public class RatePerChannelOverwrite {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RatePerChannelOverwriteId id;

    @Column(name = "rate", precision = 2, scale = 9, columnDefinition = "decimal")
    @NumberFormat(pattern = "#0.00")
    private double rate;
}
```

Is it correct to do this?

```
Voucher voucher = service.getVoucher(123456);   
Rate rate = new Rate();
rate.setVoucher(voucher);
voucher.getRates().add(rate);

RatePerChannelOverwriteId channelRateId = new RatePerChannelOverwriteId();
channelRateId.setRate(rate);   
RatePerChannelOverwrite channelRate = new RatePerChannelOverwrite();
channelRate.setId(channelRateId);
rate.getRatePerChannelOverwrites.add(channelRate);   

voucher = voucher.merge();
```

The actual exception I get is NullPointer from 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(T value)' where value is NULL, because `id` in `Rate` is still NULL (although SQL trace shows INSERT was performed on `Rate` ).

Comment: It is a good practice to have 3 entity classes.you may also go with @id instead of @ embeddedid

Comment: Yes `@Id` is required on the `@Entity` and it's working as expected. But if the 3rd entity has a composite key, you need to use `@EmbeddedId` with `@ManyToOne` instead, and this is where it's failing.

Comment: try with IdClass..make the primary class serializable

Comment: Didn't try `@IdClass` but solved by moving `@ManyToOne` out of `@Embeddable` into the `@Entity` and adding `@MapsId` to it. So I kept `@EmbeddedId`, but it holds now only integers `channelId` and `rateId`; the `@ManyToOne` is in the entity and now is annotated with `@MapsId("rateId")`